# How to split PHP array by hours

Tags: php, mysql

I am selecting all timestamps between midnight of the current day and now, from a MySQL database using `time()`. How can I group all timestamps by hour and than return an array with the count of all 24 arrays? For example at the end it should return something like this:

```
Array(0 => 60, 1 => 104, 2 => 280, ..., 23 => 50)
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the data you are retrieving?

Comment: `SELECT HOUR(timestamp), COUNT(1) FROM table GROUP BY HOUR(timestamp) WHERE ...`.

Comment: What @cbuckley wrote seems perfectly correct although you will have to to traverse the result array in order to organize data into `hour => count(*)` format. Can you show us table's structure?

Comment: My point was that MySQL can do this for you rather than loading all of the data in to PHP and doing the work there.

Comment: but with this syntax it returns only one result, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: why do you need such a splitting? what would you do with the resulting array?

Comment: im doing jquery chart and not sure if should be like this but trying

Comment: "im doing jquery" means NOTHING. What OPERATIONS you're gonna do on the data? would you aggregate it somehow, leaving only 23 items, or you need these values as well?

Comment: I did it [link](http://jsfiddle.net/RHStj/)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *, CEIL(tstamp/3600)*3600 AS byhour 
 FROM table 
 WHERE <your where goes here>
 ORDER BY byhour
```